# Why do MCU dev boards include multiple voltage regulators?

Tags: microcontroller, power, ldo, adafruit

I was examining the Adafruit ESP32-S3 feather board and noticed that it contains 2 voltage regulators.

[image: Adafruit esp32-s3 feather schematic]

It appears that one is used for powering the MCU itself, and the other is for powering I2C devices.

Is there a specific reason for this? Is it to isolate the I2C bus from the rest of the circuit (when would this be necessary)? Or simply to double the current capacity?

Comment: look at pin 3 of the regulators

Comment: ...Wow, this one got a lot of answers in very short order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they seem to be doing it here is to allow the I2C circuitry to be powered off separately from the rest; note that there's a signal line (`I2C_PWR`) going to the enable pin of one regulator, which could be used to turn it on or off while the other regulator continues providing power. This cuts down on power consumption, as the circuitry involved in I²C communications isn't powered on when it's not used.

Presumably, that signal line is controlled by the microcontroller, though it could be controlled by something else.

---

Another reason you might do this is to separate digital and analog power supplies.

If your board has both high-speed digital logic (such as a microcontroller) and sensitive analog circuitry, you want to isolate the analog circuitry from the switching noise generated by the digital part as much as possible. A simple way to do this is to put a filter between them, consisting of a few capacitors and ferrite beads, but an alternative (whether better or worse depends on the implementation, and the definition of "better" and "worse") is to supply the analog part of the board from a completely different power supply.

Answer (score 3):

It reads on the Adafruit web page for the product. Usually if a product has some feature, the explanation and usage are listed in product description or manual.

The secondary 3.3V regulator can be turned off under software control to save power so only essential parts consume current from the main regulator in low power mode while non-essential parts are powered off.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little bit of both.  The SoC [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf) specifies a *minimum* power supply capability of 500mA, which is rather close to the 600mA limit of the AP2112K and leaves precious little current available for additional peripherals.  Will the SoC be drawing half an amp most of the time?  Probably not, but the SOT25 package the AP2112K comes in has a rather high 184 C/W thermal resistance to ambient and I don't see much in the way of copper pours around them.  Even at a modest 100mA, you'd still be pushing 70C.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is done for different analog and voltage rail sections. If you were to share the 3.3VD on the Vsensor line, the sensor would see all the switching noise from the digital line.

Another way this is done is by using a ferrite in between the rails to 'block' or attenuate high frequency currents.

Another reason two voltage regulators are used is to parallel voltage regulators, but you also need 'balancing' series resistors and the output is the same voltage line. So that is not being done in this case.

Comment: You don't necessarily need balancing resistors; I've seen regulators that can actively current-share by means of some form of communication between them (in the form of usually a single wire connecting between the regulators). This is usually for more advanced regulators, though; the sort with all sorts of other fancy features as well.

Comment: Yeah, you can do fun things with current adjust pins and have a primary regulator and follower regulators, but if you just want to share a normal regulator you'll need a resistor